# Setting multiple values for a variable as "options"

Tags: variables, discord.js

I'm making my first coding project right now, a Discord BOT with discord.js. My main problem right now is setting multiple capitalization options for my prefix. The method i'm using right now for it is just `"prefix": "f.",` like all the other things in my options.json file. I would also like it to be  `"F."` for mobile users, but using the same variable `prefix`. any way how? I've only found how to set the same value to multiple variables, but my issue is the exact opposite :/

Comment: Well there are multiple ways you could do this. One way is you could set `prefix` to an array and then edit your command handler to work with the array: `"prefix": ["f.", "F."]`. Another method is keep it as it is, but change the part of the code that looks for your prefix such that it does `message.content.toLowerCase()` before checking for the prefix (in doing so, a command like `F.help` would be converted to `f.help`, so it would find the prefix in the message). Either way, you'll need to provide your `message` handler code if you want us to show you how.

Comment: When it comes to just simple capitalization, the latter is probably the better option. But if you want two or more entirely different prefixes, the former is the way to go.

Comment: Sure! Right now it gets the messages like this: ```if (message.content === `${prefix}ping`) {```

Comment: Interested in the toLowerCase one, my help command has subs that I had to do capitalization by using || and the whole command again lol

Comment: In that case, you can just change that to `if (message.content.toLowerCase() == \`${prefix}ping\`)` and it should work as intended. Or, use the answer posted by MatievisTheKat to check for the prefix first, and then do the command checks afterwards.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Simply make the message content and prefix lower case before comparing them. For example:

```js
const prefix = "f.";

client.on("message", (msg) => {
    if (message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(prefix.toLowerCase()) {
        // starts with the prefix
    }
});
```